# What should I use to bridge gap between wooden flooring and tiles

Tags: tile

Hi I’m just wondering what is best to use to bridge this gap. Because of the sizing I’m wanting to put a wide grout around outside edge rather than spread tiles apart too much. Area is 1250mm wide and tiles are 200mm wide and because of pattern don’t want to have thick grout lines in between each tile.

My thinking is I should perhaps put either a silicone or caulk strip between wood and grouted tile edge to allow for any movement - or would it not matter to just have grout right up to the wooden edge. The base underneath the tiles is concrete as it was originally my fireplace hearth.

**I’ve just updated photos with a rough layout. Looks like I won’t be able to do thick border at front as not enough room - didn’t realise there was some framing under the pantry that I can’t go past so this governs how far back the tiles can go !

Still don’t want to spread tiles too far apart lengthwise though so would the gap either side be all good to fill with just the caulk - it’s going to be close to 20mm each side.**

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tVbg.jpg)

[image]

Comment: The correct way is to cut the tiles to fit the space and have normal sized grout lines.

Comment: I’ve just updated photos so would be interested to know how you would cut these to fit please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking is correct, you should not use cement based grout between the tiles and the wood floor. Use a latex or silicone caulk for that portion. Most tile shops carry caulk that matches their grout.

[image: Here] 
This is how you can change the layout from existing.

Comment: Just updated photos so think I should use the caulk option but will the 20mm caulk width be all good ?  Thanks

Comment: The caulk manufacturer will specify the width that is acceptable, my guess is 20mm may be too wide. If it is you can change the layout of your tile. It will require cutting 4 tiles. If you don't have a tile cutter most tile shops will cut tile for a nominal charge and you'll get a nice clean cut. I'll edit into my original answer a picture of how you can change the layout.